# Power BI Data Source Error: Login Failed for data source "Unknown"

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I used to use `dataset A` in Power BI.

I switched (and double checked that I switched) to `dataset B` in Power BI.

When I upload to Power BI Report Server and schedule the report, I get

> Data source error: Login failed for data source "Unknown"
>
> [0] -1055784932: Microsoft SQL: Could not find stored procedure
> 'dataset A'.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.

I have tried deleting and recreating the refresh schedule.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the credentials in power bi? "In Power BI Desktop select File, Options and Settings and then Data Source Settings. Find the data source with the cached settings and use the "Clear Permissions" button to reset."

Comment: Same error message.

Comment: Clarification: I did what you suggested and reuploaded to Power BI Report Server. It's odd because it refreshes no problem in Power BI Desktop, it just won't refresh without an error in Power BI Report Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to do the trick:

[Clear your cache in Power BI Desktop and your Browser](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/How-to-clear-Report-cache-in-Power-BI-Service/m-p/1455158#:%7E:text=If%20it%20is%20the%20report,%2Csave%20and%20re%2Dpublish.)

Clear your cache in the file and then clear your browser history.